# NGX Bootstrap Timepicker Set Value Programmatically

Tags: angular, timepicker, ngx-bootstrap

I am using [NGX-Bootstrap Timepicker](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/timepicker). I want to be able to set the time values programatically.

If I have something like:

```
<timepicker [(ngModel)]="mytime"></timepicker>
```

and try to set the time values with something like:

```
mytime: Date = new Date();
this.mytime.setHours(0);
this.mytime.setMinutes(0);
```

it does not work. Does anybody have any other suggestions? [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vx6far)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set 'mytime' like this :

```
const time = new Date();
time.setHours(14);
time.setMinutes(0);

this.mytime = time;
```